# Getting Error "Error reading bot file. please ensure you have valid botFilePath" in Microsoft azure QnA Maker Bot Javascript file

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, botframework, azure-qna-maker

I am developing Microsoft azure QnA Maker Bot with javascript. I have added questions in knowledge based of qnamaker.io. i have created javascript project with botbuilder and create .bot file for adding services like,

{
"name":"qna-bot-v4",
"services": [
{
"type":"endpoint",
"name":"development",
"endpoint":"http://localhost:3978/api/messages",
"appId":"",
"appPassword":"",
"id":"1"
},
{
"type":"qna",
"name":"xxx-test-kb",
"kbId":"d7e734bc-6e1b-499c-80bc-42eb6db2fb3d",
"hostname":"https://xxx-qna-service.cognitiveservices.azure.com/",
"endpointKey": "78511920-63b0-4437-8a7e-9bafbac54ac3",
"subscriptionKey":"1c44011f-1da7-4239-bd15-5be74bbfc664",
"id":"123"
}
],
"padlock":"",
"version":"2.0"
}

I have updated index.js file with botbuilderconfigurations and botbuilder-config and set the path of botfile with .env file.
When i run the index.js file with command node index.js then i'm getting following error.

Error reading bot file. please ensure you have valid botFilePath

- The botFileSecret is availble under appsetting for your azure bot
- If you are running this bot locally, consider adding a new .env file
  see https://aka.ms/about-bot-file to learn more about .bot file
  D:\user\Demos\Azure_bot\qna-bot-v-4\index.js:51
  const endpointConfig = botConfig.findServiceByNameOrId(BOT_CONFIGURATION);
  ^
  TypeError: Cannot read property 'findServiceByNameOrId' of undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Consider printing the error in the try... catch block in index.js, where you're loading the Bot Configuration. `console.error(err)`, for example.                         It's possible that you're experiencing a different type of error than the one stated in the error message.
Also please refer to this similar SO [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52733264/microsoft-bot-framework-error-reading-bot-file-but-all-env-variables-are-corr).